# Python and sqlite trouble

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I can't show the data from database sqlite in python.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('db')
connection.cursor().execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (     \
                        id TEXT,                                    \
                        name TEXT,                                  \
                        avatar TEXT                                 \
                )')

# In cycle:
query = 'INSERT INTO users VALUES ("' + str(friend.id) + '", "' + friend.name + '", "' + friend.avatar +'" )'
print query
connection.cursor().execute(query)
connection.commit()

# After cycle
print connection.cursor().fetchall()
```

Sample output of query variable:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES ("111", "Some Name", "http://avatar/path" )
```

In result, **fetchall** returns empty tuple. Why?

---

UPD
Forgotten code:

```
connection.cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM users')
connection.cursor().fetchall()
```

→
[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("db")

con.execute("create table users(id, name, avatar)")

con.execute("insert into users(id, name, avatar) values (?, ?, ?)", (friend.id, friend.name, friend.avatar))
con.commit()

for row in con.execute("select * from users")
    print row

con.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

INSERT does not return data.  To get the data back out, you'll have to issue a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `create table` string as displayed is syntactically invalid Python, as is the `insert into` string.

Comment: I think he's referring to the quotes, although I'm guessing that the mismatch is not really present in your code since you don't get a Python syntax error, and since the INSERT statement prints out ok.

Comment: @larry-lustig @msw oh sorry, that's my fault. There is passing constant string and I forgot to take out the quotes after replacing it with simple string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer to your first question is: because you use different cursors.

`connection.cursor()` creates a new cursor in the connection you created before. `fetchall()` gives you the results of the query you executed before in that same cursor. I.e. what you did was this:

```
# After cycle
cursor1 = connection.cursor()
cursor1.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
cursor2 = connection.cursor()
cursor2.execute("")
cursor2.fetchall()
```

What you should have done was this:

```
# After cycle
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
print cursor.fetchall()
```